# AttributeError: module 'graphing' has no attribute 'scatter_2D'

Tags: attributes

```
#en jupyter y en colab da eror , en azure no
import graphing

# Show a graph of the result
# Don't worry about how this works for now
graphing.scatter_2D(dataset,label_x="harness_size", 
                        label_y="boot_size",
                        trendline=lambda x: fitted_model.params[1] * x + fitted_model.params[0])

 -______________________________
  4 import graphing
  6 # Show a graph of the result
  7 # Don't worry about how this works for now
```

----> 8 graphing.scatter_2D(dataset,    label_x="harness_size",
9                                 label_y="boot_size",
10                                 trendline=lambda x: fitted_model.params[1] * x + fitted_model.params[0]
11                                 )

AttributeError: module 'graphing' has no attribute 'scatter_2D'

```
a cambiar por :



import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(dataset,x="harness_size",y="boot_size",title='Botas y arneses')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What happens is that in practice in a previous cell a file called "graphing.py" is downloaded.

[image: Image jupyter notebook]

What I did was copy the code that is in the jupyter notebook cell link and paste it into a new .py file called graphing.

After that restart vs code and there it worked for me.